# Carousel "next" and "prev" function not work in single page application SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Carousel in SPA using this code. I am new with bootstrap

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
  <a href="#discription" role="image">
    <img src="cloth5.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="100%" height="auto">
</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="cloth5.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="460" height="345">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="menjeans.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="460" height="345">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="menjeans.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="460" height="345">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

But when I click on `Next` or `Prev` arrow buttons that find page `#myCarousel` rather shows next slide. Please help what I do.

Comment: A. any errors in the `console`? B. you should call `$("#myCarousel").carousel();` after once the carousel added to the DOM. Try it and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the banner inside `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">`

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
  <a href="#discription" role="image">
    <img src="cloth5.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="100%" height="auto">
</a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="cloth5.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="460" height="345">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="menjeans.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="460" height="345">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="menjeans.jpg" alt="Loading..." width="460" height="345">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issue removing href value and add

> data-target="#myCarousel

as property of anchor tag `<a class="left carousel-control" href data-target="#myCarousel"  role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href data-target="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>`

Comment: Solved my issue . Not sure why though.